# Launch Client Console App from Web Page

Tags: asp.net, clickonce

I've been asked to launch a Console App from a WebPage. Sounds hairy, but there is sound logic for it.

Basically, the page is a Dashboard page which only super admins can access. **We have a Console app which needs to run on the client machine. It cannot run headlessly on the server.**

I figured I'd have some kind of small file which is downloaded upon the button click. Then that file could be run from the resulting dialog which would launch the exe.

I know apple does something like that with podcasts. You can subscribe by downloading a small link that would behave as I described and open iTunes.

I had a quick go using ClickOnce, publishing the application to IISExpress where I had my site up and running, but had no success with that.

Is ClickOnce the way to go, or is there some other easier approach?

I've also tried just adding a shortcut with a link to that shortcut nd adding .lnk as a mime type in IIS with mimeType="application/octet-stream". I had no luck there and received a 404 error which I have not been able to resolve yet.

Edit
I should also mention that the Console application is not just a single exe assembly. It has dependencies on a bunch of other 3rd party dlls.

Comment: ClickOnce will work. Or just putting the executable up there on the server and linking to it. But if you've already deployed the app to everyone's PC, I'd update the app to recognize certain URL's (either by file extension or scheme) and then have the app respond to those. Or you could use [PSEXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897553.aspx) on the server to start the program on the client (non-interactively).

Comment: What is this console app supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming here that this desktop application needs to be executed at client side. Thus it will be installed by you or someone in your department i.e available to download.

If it is the case then what you need is to register URI - just like skype URI where href="skype:28347839" lanuches skype automatically.

For reference please click here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

otherwise, get clickonce - -choice is yours.

Comment: I had another shot at clickonce. It seems elmah is getting in the way. Even after I disable the elmah httpmodule in Web.config. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: Hard to find the reason out straight, probably need to check manifest/config or thing else. How about checking some videos on youtube, such as : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4BTLdIMYEY

Comment: Finally got ClickOnce working. Hosted it in a separate IIS site and used IE. There may be a chrome plugiun. Will check that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, just put the console application (an .exe file) on the server, and link to it in a webpage. When the user clicks on the link the exe file will be downloaded. The user can then run the exe file on their own computer.

There will be some warning dialogs about security issues, but if your users trust your exe then they can accept those warnings.

If you get the console application [signed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and/or maybe use Group Policy on your LAN you might be able to reduce or [eliminate those warnings](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/).

Comment: I should have mentioned that the Console app is not confined to a single exe file. It draws on a bunch of another 3rd party dlls. I'll edit the question to add that now.

Comment: Okay then I guess the exe will either need to be an installer, or a click once application.